# Filtering for all buildings with given house number on given streets using OverPass Turbo?

Tags: overpass-api

I already created the following script to filter for all `living_street`s in a known `postal_code`.

```
area[postal_code="12345"]->.a;
(way(area.a)["highway"="living_street"];
 rel(area.a)["highway"="living_street"])->.w;
(.w;.w >;)->.w;
.w out;
(._;>;);
out skel;
```

Now I need all buildings with a known `housenumber`.
My problem is that I found no way to get the buildings on the streets/ ways.

Comment: What is your question? Don't you find suitable tags from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses?

Comment: @user30184 Sure I find the tags. The problem was how to formulate the query to get the buildings belonging to a street which is just not possible, when I understand answer 1 right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will return all buildings with `addr:housenumber` tag in your postal code area:

```
area[postal_code="12345"]->.a;
way(area.a)[building]["addr:housenumber"];
out geom;
```

Apart from that it's not quite clear, what you mean by "I found no way to get the buildings on the streets/ ways.". If you need some kind of restriction to the ways, which have previously been found, that's currently not yet possible with v0.7.53. The only chance as of today would be to leverage an associatedStreet relation, which may not be in use in your area.

Comment: Reformulated the question would be how to get all buildings associated or related to the ways (streets) I already found, so that I can later filter them further based on the houseNumber. I think that is want you mean by "restriction to the ways, which have previously been found" so I guess it is currently not possible.